# (NativeScript - BottomNavigation) How to redirect from one tab to another with button

Tags: nativescript, tabstrip

I am using this (https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation) git (https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng)

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
    path: "", 
    redirectTo: "/tabs/default",         
    pathMatch: "full" 
},
{
    path: "login", 
    component: LoginComponent
},    
{
    path: "tabs",
    loadChildren: "~/app/tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

];

tabs.module.ts

```
NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: "default", component: TabsComponent, children: [
                {
                    path: "events",
                    outlet: "eventTab",
                    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                    loadChildren: "~/app/event/events.module#EventsModule",
                },
                {
                    path: "notifications",
                    outlet: "notificationTab",
                    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                    loadChildren: "~/app/notifications/notifications.module#NotificationsModule",
                },
                {
                    path: "profile",
                    outlet: "profileTab",
                    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                    loadChildren: "~/app/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule",
                },
                {
                    path: "info",
                    outlet: "infoTab",
                    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                    loadChildren: "~/app/info/info.module#InfoModule",
                }                    
            ]
        }
    ])
```

notifications.module.ts

```
NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
        { path: "", redirectTo: "notifications" },
        { path: "notifications", component: NotificationsComponent },           
    ]),
```

In notifications view i have list with records, when i click on the record i want to redirect to events tab. I tried many ways but nothing works :(

for example, with this I have no errors, but redirect also not working

```
this.routerExtensions.navigate([
    'tabs/default', { outlets: { eventTab: ["events"] } }
  ])
```

Do You have any ideas?

Comment: You can not change the active tab with router, set selectedIndex on bottom navigation control then use router to navigate on active tab.

Comment: thx @Manoj but how to set selectedIndex in notifications component, tabs are in tabs component?

Comment: Use a Service & Subject, update subject from notifications component and listen to changes from tab component and update the index on the tab component. Should be quite straight forward.